Quadratic equation with a relation between its coefficients
Given the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a, b, c \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $4(a+b)+7c=0$, $(a\neq0)$ prove that:

All of the quadratic's roots are real.
Atleast one of the roots is in the $[0, 1]$ intervall.

Proving the first statement was easy. Since $4(a+b)+7c=0$, this means: $$c=-\frac{4(a+b)}{7}$$
A quadratic's roots are all real, if $\Delta\ge0$, so:
$$b^2-4ac\ge0$$
$$b^2+\frac{16a(a+b)}{7}\ge0$$
$$7b^2+16ab+16a^2\ge0$$
$$3b^2+(4a+2b)^2\ge0$$
Which is true for $\forall a,b \in\mathbb{R}$.
I also have an idea for the second one, but I am a little bit sceptical about it. So let's cosider two cases:
a) a>0
$$0\le\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\le1$$
Since a>0, getting rid of the denominator won't change the inequality.
$$0\le-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\le2a$$
Addig $b$ to every side results in:
$$b\le\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\le2a+b$$
And here I ran into confusion. If the square root is with minus, only the right hand side inequality will be true. If it is with plus, only the left hand side one. How do I go on?

I think the second part is a lot easier than that - I should look for a different idea

Did you meant the Viete formulas?

No - I was thinking of evaluating the polynomial at the endpoints of the interval (as in the now accepted answer). Doing that also solves the real root part (if one root is real, both are).

The second one goes like this.
Given:
$$4a+4b+7c=0$$
$$\implies 4a+4b+4c=-3c$$
$$\implies a+b+c=-3c/4$$
$F(0)=c$ and $f(1)=a+b+c$.
So, $f(0)\cdot f(1) = c \cdot(a+b+c) = -3c^2/4$.
Which is always negative.this implies that function takes
Opposite signs at $x=0$ and $x=1$.
So by the intermediate mean value theorem there must be a root for
$f(x)=0$ in between $0$ and $1$

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I haven't thought about such a solution...thank you!

I think there is one thing that is missing. $-3c^2/4$ can be equal to $0$ when $c = 0$ so it is not always negative. However then we have $f(0) = 0$ so we are still done.

Wouldn't that mean that both of the roots are between [0,1]?

Indeed under given condition we have if $c = 0$ then the expression have two roots: $0$ and $1$.

If c equal to zero then 0 is one of the roots and a equals to -b so 1 is the second root.so this directly proves the second part of question.
